# Cant use system.web.security and HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in dot net core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to migrate from ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.5 to ASP.NET Core 6,
I can't use `System.Web.Security` any more.

I also can't use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. Please suggest an alternative to implement the same functionality:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

using Ibq.Wages.ManagementSystem.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Ibq.Wages.ManagementSystem.AppStart
{
    public class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
        public int UserCompanyId { get; set; }
        public string PayerQid { get; set; }
        public string PayerEid { get; set; }
        public bool OTPCompleted { get; set; }
        public int? AuthorizationLevels { get; set; } 

        private PIBQWS_prodContext context = new PIBQWS_prodContext();

        public override string ApplicationName { get; set; }

        public CustomRoleProvider()
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) == false)
                UserCompany(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: In `.Net6`, we can use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to get the name. Have a look at [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  to know more about storage providers .